# R Markdown Flexdashboard plot/graph cut-off at the top

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I have created an `htmlwidget` in R and I'd like to include this in a Flexdasboard. I am able to generate the widget and save it as a `".html"` file. Then using R Markdown I insert the widget into my `.rmd` file using `htmltools::includeHTML("filename.html")` The problem is when I `Knit to flex_dashboard` the plot/graph is cut-off at the top. Does anyone know why or how to solve for this? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Just solved with this:

```
### Plot

<iframe src="mypage.html" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: Please explain how the suggested update would solve the problem described in the original question.